# Directly access cloud as data directory

Tags: windows, google-drive-api, cloud

In one of the windows desktop application(always internet connected) I want to use cloud storage(could be anything like google drive or any other) real time always. Please let me know how can it be done.

I understand this is not the issue but the question is opinion based, but I need help, thats why posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

Google has real-time databases, check these:

- Get started with [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart)
- Get started with [Firebase Realtime DB](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)